# How do I prevent a service from stopping in the ServiceHandler function?

Tags: c++

I created a Windows service, hoping that when a user (or other program) wants to pause or stop it, it needs user confirmation (such as some anti-virus software).
When I try to pause it (using services.msc), it works as expected, but the prompt service does not return an error (but I clearly set
dwWin32ExitCode to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);
However, when I want to stop it, the first time it works normally (still prompt does not return an error), and then any control over the service will prompt error 1061 "The service cannot accept control messages at this time." I can only terminate this process.

So I want to know:

1. How do I prevent a service from stopping in the ServiceHandler function?
2. I modified my application to set the error immediately when someone is trying to stop it. It is found that the error code can be set with dwWin32ExitCode when the service is starting, but not during the stop process. How to set the error code during service stop and continue running the service?

There are some of my code:

```
// svcmain.h
/* I already included required headers */
// 添加MessageBoxTimeout支持
extern "C" {
    int WINAPI MessageBoxTimeoutA(IN HWND hWnd, IN LPCSTR lpText, IN LPCSTR lpCaption,
        IN UINT uType, IN WORD wLanguageId, IN DWORD dwMilliseconds);
    int WINAPI MessageBoxTimeoutW(IN HWND hWnd, IN LPCWSTR lpText, IN LPCWSTR lpCaption,
        IN UINT uType, IN WORD wLanguageId, IN DWORD dwMilliseconds);
};

typedef struct _mpc_rule_t {

} mpc_rule_t;

class ServiceWorker_c {
public:
    ServiceWorker_c() { ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(*this)); };
    ~ServiceWorker_c() = default;
    SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus;
    SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hServiceStatusHandle;
    HANDLE svcmainthread_handle;
    CHAR   ServiceName[256];
//  string cfg_path;
//  HANDLE cfgfilelk;
//  vector<mpc_rule_t> rules;
    //HANDLE hPipeServer;
    //HANDLE hpSubProcess;
    bool pause_needs_confirm, stoppable;
    bool exit;

    static void WINAPI ServiceLaunch_main(DWORD, LPWSTR*);
//  static void WINAPI ReportErrorAndExit(DWORD dwErrCode);
//  static void WINAPI ServiceHandler(DWORD fdwControl);
    static void WINAPI srv_core_thread(LPVOID);
//  void WINAPI parseConfig();
//  //static DWORD WINAPI thPipeServer(PVOID);

protected:
    //static void PipeDataHandler(HANDLE pipe, string command);
    void _findrules(tinyxml2::XMLElement* el);
};

extern ServiceWorker_c* global_SvcObj;
```

```
// svcmain.cpp
ServiceWorker_c* global_SvcObj;
static DWORD SvcShowMessage(
    LPWSTR lpszMessage, LPWSTR lpszTitle, DWORD style, DWORD timeout
) {
    DWORD dwSession = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    DWORD dwResponse = 0;
    WTSSendMessageW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwSession,
        lpszTitle,
        static_cast<DWORD>((wcslen(lpszTitle) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)),
        lpszMessage,
        static_cast<DWORD>((wcslen(lpszMessage) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)),
        style, timeout, &dwResponse, FALSE);
    return dwResponse;
}
void WINAPI ServiceWorker_c::ServiceHandler(DWORD fdwControl)
{
    switch (fdwControl)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN: {
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
        SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle,
            &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus);
        ExitProcess(0);
        break;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: {
            /*auto& ss = global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus;
            ss.dwWin32ExitCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
            ss.dwCheckPoint = 0;
            ss.dwWaitHint = 0;
            break; */ /*This is unuseful */
        auto last_stat = global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 16384;
        SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle,
            &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus);

        if (global_SvcObj->pause_needs_confirm)
        if (!PauseOrStopConfirm("exit")) {
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;
            auto& ss = global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus;
            ss.dwWin32ExitCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED; 
            ss.dwCurrentState = last_stat;
            ss.dwCheckPoint = 0;
            ss.dwWaitHint = 0;
            SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle, &ss); 
#if defined(_DEBUG) && 0
            SvcShowMessage((LPWSTR)to_wstring(ss.dwWin32ExitCode).c_str(),
                (LPWSTR)L"Debug", MB_ICONINFORMATION, 3000);
// The dialog here shows that dwWin32ExitCode is really 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
#endif
            return;
        }

        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;
        // Stopping clean
        SetLastError(0);
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 6258)
        ::TerminateThread(global_SvcObj->svcmainthread_handle, 0);
        global_SvcObj->exit = true;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;

#pragma warning(pop)

        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
        break;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE: {
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 16384;
        SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle,
            &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus);
        if (global_SvcObj->pause_needs_confirm) do {
            if (PauseOrStopConfirm("pause")) break;
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 5;
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
            global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
            SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle,
                &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus); // It works
            return;
        } while (0);
        SuspendThread(global_SvcObj->svcmainthread_handle);
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_PAUSED;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
        //if (global_SvcObj->stoppable && global_SvcObj->pause_needs_confirm)
        //  global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
        break;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE: {
        //if (global_SvcObj->pause_needs_confirm)
        //  global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted &= ~SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
        break;
    }
    default:
        return;
    };
    SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle, &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus);
}

void WINAPI ServiceWorker_c::ServiceLaunch_main(DWORD, LPWSTR*) {
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 16384;
    global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerW
    (s2wc(global_SvcObj->ServiceName), ServiceHandler);
    if (global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle == 0)
    {
        DWORD nError = GetLastError();
        return;
    }

    //add your init code here
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;

    SetCurrentDirectoryW(s2wc(GetProgramInfo().path));

    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;

    //add your service thread here

    global_SvcObj->svcmainthread_handle = 
        (HANDLE)::_beginthread(srv_core_thread, 0, global_SvcObj);
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;

    // Initialization complete - report running status 
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
    global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted |=
        SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE;
//#pragma warning(push)
//#pragma warning(disable: 6387)
    if (!SetServiceStatus(global_SvcObj->hServiceStatusHandle,
        &global_SvcObj->ServiceStatus)) {
//#pragma warning(pop)
        ::exit(1);
    }

}

void WINAPI ServiceWorker_c::srv_core_thread(LPVOID) {
    while (1) Sleep(MAXDWORD);
    // Because this is the smallest code to reproduce, the main thread is only sleep
    return;
}
```

*I am a rookie. I would appreciate it if you could help me.*

> You can find the full code at [My GitHub repo](https://github.com/shc0743/CLearn/blob/main/MyProcessControl/MyProcessControl_UsermodeHost/svcmain.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-handler-function):

> If a service accepts the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP control code, it must stop upon receipt, going to either the SERVICE_STOP_PENDING or SERVICE_STOPPED state. After the SCM sends this control code, it will not send other control codes.

However, it then goes on to say:

> **Windows XP:** If the service returns **NO_ERROR** and continues to run, it continues to receive control codes. This behavior changed starting with Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2).

So it looks like you can just ignore the stop request and return `NO_ERROR`.  Maybe returning `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` is upsetting the SCM.

Comment: But it's not useful after Windows XP.  I changed the dwWin32ExitCode to ```NO_ERROR```, and run it in win10. It is same as ```ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED```. In fact, the document indicates "If a service accepts the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP control code, it must stop upon receipt". Maybe I can only achieve this goal by making the service stop only when it is suspended. Thanks for your helping.